# How to make it possible to add products to a cart for everyone, even non authorized people

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I try to add a product to a cart as guest, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
No Session matches the given query.
Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/la-fleur-fily-suvignuion/
Raised by:  shop.views.Product
Using the URLconf defined in lafleurlily.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
about/ [name='about_us']
near_me/ [name='find_near_me']
contact-us/ [name='contact_us']
store/ [name='all_products']
store/ category/wines/ [name='wine_category']
store/ category/sparkling/ [name='sparkling_category']
store/ <slug:wine_slug>/ [name='each_wine']
The current path, store/la-fleur-fily-suvignuion/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings
file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

orders/views.py:

```
class CartPage(View):
    template = 'orders/cart.html'

    def get(self, request):
        session_key = request.session.session_key
        session = get_object_or_404(Session, session_key=session_key)

        cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, session=session)
        items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart_items=cart)

        def item_total():
            summ = 0
            for each in items:
                print(each.product.price, each.quantity)
                summ = summ + each.product.price * each.quantity
            return float(summ)

        context = {
            'cart': cart,
            'item': items,
            'item_total': item_total()
            }
        return render(request, self.template, context)
```

shop/views.py:

```
class Product(View): #SubscribePost,
    template = 'shop/product.html'
    model = Wine

    def get(self, request, wine_slug):
        product = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug=wine_slug)
        context = {'wine': product}
        return render(request, self.template, context=context)

    def post(self, request, wine_slug):
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        if action == 'add_to_cart':
            return self.add_to_cart(request, wine_slug)

    def add_to_cart(self, request, wine_slug):
        session_key = request.session.session_key
        if session_key is None:
            request.session.create()

        session = get_object_or_404(Session, session_key=session_key)
        product = Wine.objects.get(slug=wine_slug)

        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(session=session)
        cart_item, item_created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart_items=cart, product=product)
        if cart_item:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
            cart_item.save()

        return redirect('cart')
```

orders/models.py:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('CartItem', null=True, default=None)
    date_generation = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_generation)


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart_items = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Wine, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):`
       return str(self.pk)
```

I want users without an account to also be able to add to a cart.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can do it.
The same matter happened to me too. I solved the problem instead of using this code:

```
if session_key is None:
        request.session.create()
```

with this one:

```
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
       request.session['cached_session_key'] = request.session.session_key
```

You now have the session.
In my case I solved the problem.
I hope to be proved helpful.

Comment: it still don't work and give me whis error:

Comment: I believe you don't have the session yet.
Check with [print(request.session.session_key)] whether it is None or not. Personally I verify the visitor has the session before carrying out any action. In your case when you open the cart page, not when the visitor sends the post

Answer (score 0):

it still don't work and give me whis error:

```
Page not found (404)
No Session matches the given query.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/la-fleur-lily-red-dry/
Raised by:  shop.views.Product
Using the URLconf defined in lafleurlily.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
about/ [name='about_us']
near_me/ [name='find_near_me']
contact-us/ [name='contact_us']
store/ [name='all_products']
store/ category/wines/ [name='wine_category']
store/ category/sparkling/ [name='sparkling_category']
store/ <slug:wine_slug>/ [name='each_wine']
The current path, store/la-fleur-lily-red-dry/, matched the last one.
```